# Search words in the document and put them into Array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I would like to search with regex pattern for certain words in the document. If word meets criteria then put it in the Array[].

```
function findXtext3() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var rangeElements = [];
  var rangeElement=null;

  while (rangeElement = body.findText('[{].+?[}]',rangeElement))
  {
    rangeElements.push(rangeElement);
  }

  var zmienna = rangeElements[0];

  var text = body.editAsText();

  text.appendText(zmienna);
}
```

Comment: 'zmienna.getElement().getText())' returns full document text instead of 
the first element in array. I would like to put all finded words into array['word1','word2','word3'] and echo/print them seperatly ie. word1

Comment: If `RangeElement.getElement()` returns the full body text, then you have only one element in the document... note that `RangeElement` does NOT give just the word matched. It tells you **where the word is in the element**

Comment: Ok. Logger.log(rangeElements[0].getStartOffset());  give me a integer where the searching word starts. Logger.log(rangeElements[1].getStartOffset()); give me a second startOffset. Is there a method to getText(startOffset,EndOffset)??

Comment: Please edit your question to illustrate your specific issue. Right now, your question essentially states that the implementation of the function follows the specification found in documentation, i.e. there is no issue whatsoever. If you need to learn how to work with a JavaScript `String`, such as the one returned by `Element#getText()`, then consult your preferred JavaScript developer reference. If you have a specific task you are attempting to accomplish, and are trying to use these methods to achieve that task, but encountering issues and difficulties, I recommend elaborating on that.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Now i know that's not an issue. I thought this method will work like in other languages. I changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a solution in github examples https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/blob/master/docs/translate/translate.gs

after getText() method i used substring() with start offset and end which gives me exactly the word which i searched in the document by regex pattern.

```
var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();

// Echo value
Logger.log(foundText.getText()**.substring(start, end +1)**);
```